# Removing Bower from Workflow and Migrating to npm

Tags: npm, workflow, bower

With `npm` becoming more and more popular by the day, I feel as though there is less of a need for me to continue using `bower` in my workflow.

I have read several articles on why the above is true, but have yet to find a guide detailing the steps one should take in order to smoothly and successfully migrate from `bower` to `npm` and then remove `bower` altogether.

I was hoping to find some more guidance here on how to do so. Anyone have any experience with this or tips?

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you've already read through this blog post
https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
but, it should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend to you to migrate to [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) instead of npm. It does all the things done by npm with some more feature and also being more performing.

Their main differences are: Bower works with a *bower.json* file, Yarn and npm work with a *package.json* file but the content of these files are almost similar (package name, version, description, etc.); Bower saves by default its modules into the **bower_components** folder, the other two in the **node_modules** folder.

Assuming that you probably already have a *bower.json* file the steps are the following:

Init a new package inserting the asked informations:

```
$ yarn init # or 'npm init'
```

Then you could copy the **dependencies** and **devDependencies** from your *bower.json* file to the new *package.json* file OR I recommend to install them manually. Example:

```
$ yarn add jquery bootstrap # or 'npm install --save jquery bootstrap'
$ yarn add -D webpack babel # or 'npm install --save-dev webpack babel'
```

I hope it was helpful :)